# Does Thunderbird's Extension Webmail Encrypts Passwords?

Tags: security, thunderbird, encryption

I've just set up my Yahoo Mail account to be checked from Thunderbird using it's webmail extension http://webmail.mozdev.org/ , and my concern is about security. I'm not sure how does this extension works and I'm wondering if I'm sending my login information to the Internet in plain text.

Any comments about this?

Thanks in advance

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Well... in delving through the webmail.mozdev.org site, the forum, and whatnot... I found this lil nugget.

> The Webmail extensions play absolutely no role whatsoever in the storing or management of passwords - that is function entirely confined to the main Thunderbird program.

Which means that you really mean to ask if Thunderbird sends passwords in plain text or encrypted.

And considering that Thunderbird seems to take encryption pretty seriously...
[image: Thunderbird server Encryption warning]...

I would say that they intend to keep your password as safe as possible.